# $(\infty,n)$-operads?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, operads

I wonder whether there is (or should be) a theory of colored $(\infty,n)$-operads or multicategories?

We know that *multicategories* are generalizations of categories, and *nonsymmetric colored $\infty$-operads* are generalizations of $\infty$-categories. Given that we have theories of $(\infty,n)$-categories, it seems natural to expect analogues for nonsymmetric operads. I also wonder the same for (symmetric) colored operads.

This grew out of discussions under https://mathoverflow.net/a/407227, which leads me to suspicion of existence of "delooping" of colored $\infty$-operads, which should be $(\infty,2)$ if exists.

Answer (score 2):

Higher operads are discussed in one form in Leinster's [Higher Operads, Higher Categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305049).

Likewise, there is a notion of 2-operads as an analogue of $2$-categories. See for instance [$(A_\infty,2)$-categories and relative $2$-operads](https://higher-structures.math.cas.cz/api/files/issues/Vol5Iss1/BottmanCarmeli).
Along the same path, I've seen 2-dendroidal sets appear in [this paper](https://www.math.uakron.edu/%7Esf34/globe.pdf) of Stefan Forcey.

Of course, these are not necessarily the kind of higher operads you are after.

At this stage, my understanding is that we still have a hell of a lot to learn about $(\infty,1)$-operads, and examples thereof take care of most applications. I'm not aware of any application for a theory $(\infty,n)$-operads in current research, but I would very much like to see one.